# calling inkscape cli from php with shell_exec, return different value than running directly from cmd

Tags: php, svg, shell-exec, inkscape

I need to get height of a text from SVG files (id : textmaster) with php.

When running inkscape with shell_exec, the return value is different than running it directly from cmd :

```
<?php
        $heightpx = shell_exec('inkscape --query-id="textmaster" --query-height drawing_edit.svg');
        echo $heightpx;
?>
```

the return value was :

```
74.5301
```

But when run directly from cmd :

```
inkscape --query-id="textmaster" --query-height drawing_edit.svg
```

the return value was :

```
128.778
```

the svg files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:25.4773px;line-height:1.25;font-family:Austria;-inkscape-font-specification:Austria;stroke-width:0.367463"
       x="20.467245"
       y="47.263172"
       id="textmaster"><tspan
         id="tspan7489"
         x="20.467245"
         y="47.263172"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-family:Austria;-inkscape-font-specification:Austria;stroke-width:0.367463">Hello World!</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The right value was when it run directly from cmd prompt.
How to make the shell_exec called from php return the same values?

Comment: You are using `mm` units for page size. That might be a hint that different DPI values are used to compute px values. The reason could be different config files used. Try running `inkscape --user-data-directory` in both environments. If they differ, force the use of the right directory by setting the `INKSCAPE_PROFILE_DIR` environment variable. I would be suprised if `inkscape --sysem-data-directory` differs, but for completeness, you should try it also. The related env variable is `INKSCAPE_DATADIR`.

Comment: Environment path was same, and it was the same svg file that i process using the same inkscape with the shell_exec and called directly from command prompt, the result is different.